# Can I use an infinitive with the verb 'recommend'?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

According to this [source](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_list.htm) the verb 'recommend' can be used only with a gerund, but I've found some examples with an infinitive:

> 1) We **recommend you to update** your browser
>
> 2) We **recommend you to use** REGULAR ELICINA that does not contain any moisturizers, which is good for it will avoid the greasiness of the skin
>
> 3) We **recommend you to check** the privacy policies of such service providers to understand how they process your location data
>
> 4) If your plans are to apply for a permanent visa, Escalar **recommend you to contact** with Arrive Australia Migration Services for additional information
>
> 5) To avoid the Megaproject Paradox, **we recommend you to study** the points described above, and report your management and Sponsors

Question:

> Can I use an infinitive with the verb 'recommend'?

Comment: Yes you can. You can even use the bare infinitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of those examples sound somewhat strange to me, and several of them contain other grammatical errors that suggest they were not composed by a native speaker. The *recommend you to...* construction is marginal compared to *recommend that you...*, as you can see from this [Google Ngrams chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recommend+you+to%2C+recommend+that+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecommend%20you%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecommend%20that%20you%3B%2Cc0).

I've rewritten below the sentences as I would prefer them, with my changes highlighted.

> We recommend **that** you update your browser
>
> We recommend **that** you use REGULAR ELICINA, **which** does not contain any moisturizers, which is good for it will avoid the greasiness of the skin

It's more natural in this sentence to use a relative clause beginning with *which* than with *that*, since the clause seems to contribute additional information rather than specify a particular entity, like in the noun phrase *the man that I saw*, where *that I saw* helps you pick out exactly which man I'm talking about.

> 3) We recommend **that** you check the privacy policies of such service providers to understand how they process your location data
>
> 4) If your plans are to apply for a permanent visa, Escalar recommend**s** **that** you contact Arrive Australia Migration Services for additional information

You can contact someone, but it sounds decidedly strange to contact **with** someone, so I've deleted that preposition from the original sentence.

> 5) To avoid the Megaproject Paradox, we recommend **that** you study the points described above, and report **to** your management and **s**ponsors

It looks like this sentence is incomplete so I'm not sure what it's supposed to be, but it seems like it should be *report to your management and sponsors* and not *report your management and sponsors*. The noun *sponsors* should not be capitalized.

Note that these judgments are strictly for American English and I cannot comment on how these sentences fare in other varieties of English.