# Subjunctive & Gerund

Tags: gerunds, subjunctives

> When a doctor recommends you take a test or have some surgery, ask
>   whether the doctor would suggest that his or her spouse or children go
>   through such a procedure.

I found the above line in [Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/healthy-living/japanese-doctor-shigeaki-hinohara-st-lukes-international-university-fun-a7864786.html) news.

My question is this - why "take" here?  Shouldn't it be either "recommends that you take" or "recommends your taking"?

So far I know we use subjunctive or gerund with "recommend".

Comment: See probable duplicate [Gerund and infinitives for “Suggest and Recommend”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62945/). Also [Can I use an infinitive with the verb 'recommend'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/) and doubtless others.

Answer (score 1):

The subordinating conjunction *that* can be omitted, and this is very common in informal style (and I note that the quote is taken from direct speech).

"When a doctor recommends that you take" can become "When a doctor recommends you take".

There are two "subjunctives" in the sentence (I put the term "subjunctive" in quotes because the use of the term is a bit controversial, especially in cases like this where the subjunctive and indicative have identical form):

> When a doctor recommends you **take** a test or have some surgery, ask whether the doctor would suggest that his or her spouse or children **go** through such a procedure.

The second one has a "that" preceding the subordinate clause, while the first one has no "that".

"Recommends your taking" would be OK as well ("have" would then become "having"), although rather formal - and "recommends you taking" (again, with "having") would also work (in a less formal style):

> When a doctor recommends your **taking** a test or **having** some surgery, ask whether the doctor would suggest that his or her spouse or children go through such a procedure.
>
> When a doctor recommends you **taking** a test or **having** some surgery, ask whether the doctor would suggest that his or her spouse or children go through such a procedure.